Covariant and invariant collections in python typing
There is a problem that I have come across in python that the List type is invariant - meaning that it can only hold objects of a specific type or you will get a type error (for example when running mypy) - but sometimes you need to use a collection in a more generic function which can accept all types of a base class (lets call it A) as well as all derived classes. A clear example is this
class A:
    pass
   
class B(A):
    pass

def print_list_a(my_list: list[A]) -> None:
    print(my_list)

l1 = [A()]
l2 = [B()]

print_list_a(l1)
print_list_a(l2) 

When I run the above with mypy in strict mode I get the following
main.py:41: error: Argument 1 to "print_list_a" has incompatible type "list[B]"; expected "list[A]"  [arg-type]
main.py:41: note: "List" is invariant
main.py:41: note: Consider using "Sequence" instead, which is covariant

Can you explain what the note re invariant and covariant types means and the best way to solve it?

Depends on what you need: does it have to be a list? I.e. do you need methods that only list has? Then your function must accept a list. Or do you want your interface to be more generic? Should it also accept tuples or other "Sequences"? Then your function must accept a Sequence - this advice holds for all types that implement some kind of interface

I rephrased this to QA to better fit stackoverflow format

First of all, for the sake of clarity, I'd like to change the definition of print_list_a as follows:
def print_list_a(my_list: list[A]) -> None:
    a: A
    for a in my_list:
      print(a)

Otherwise, one might ask, why not just make the parameter type Any?:
def print_list_a(a: Any) -> None:
    print(a)

Now to answer your question regarding MyPy's errors, there are two things at play:

l2 is being inferred as a list[B], as that is the narrowest type that would satisfy MyPy.
lists in Python are invariant, which means B being a (subclass of) A does not have any bearing on the relationship between list[B] and list[A]

Specifically, it does not mean list[B] is a (subclass of) list[A], as that would require lists to be covariant
Not really related to the question, but for completeness, it also does not means the opposite (list[A] is a (subclass of) list[B]), which require lists to be contravariant.



So taking the two points above together, you can only pass list[A]s into print_list_a(...). Specifically, you cannot pass list[B]s, as list[B]s are not list[A]s.
So you can fix the code by changing one of the above:
1. Make it so that l2 is a list[A] by explicitly annotating it:
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

def print_list_a(my_list: list[A]) -> None:
    a: A
    for a in my_list:
      print(a)

l1: list[A] = [A()]
l2: list[A] = [B()]

print_list_a(l1)
print_list_a(l2)

2. Make print_list_a take a covariant parameter such that some collection[B] is a (subclass of) some collection[A]:
This is only an option if you have access to the source code of print_list_a, and that print_list_a does not add elements to the my_list parameter.
But as long as that's true, you can use a covariant collection type (such as the read-only Sequence), and it basically looks like the answer you provided:
from typing import Sequence

class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

def print_list_a(my_list: Sequence[A]) -> None:
    a: A
    for a in my_list:
      print(a)

l1 = [A()]
l2 = [B()]

print_list_a(l1)
print_list_a(l2)

What if the function adds elements to the list?
To expand on why covariance does not work when the function adds to the list, consider this example:
def append_and_print_list_a(my_list: list[A]) -> None:
    my_list.append(A()) # Note we are adding an A to the list, which is legal
    a: A
    for a in my_list:
      print(a)

l2: list[B] = [B()]

append_and_print_list_a(l2) # Does not compile

We are saying:

l2 is a list that contains only Bs (not As)
In append_and_print_list_a, we are appending an A() to my_list

The code, if allowed to type-check, would cause the two points above to be in conflict.

If you run this in mypy on strict mode you will get an error. Actually this was my first try adn the reason for this post. I settled on using the bound type as described in my answer below, but had a suggestion from someone that I shoudl use sequence instead of list as it is a covariant type. I really wonder about what the implications of that are

Out of curiosity, what is the MyPy error?

Ah sorry I read this in a rush I didn't notice you had typed l2 to list[A]. Reran this way letting mypy know it was a list A and this passed fine! Perhaps this is the simplest thing to do here?

Is there a case where you would use the Sequence rather than do this though? You mentioned in your comment about the different effects of reading and writing from the list?

I have to admit, my knowledge (and comments here) are more based generally on covariance/contravariance/invariance not specific to Python (they apply to generics in other languages as well).
I'm not really that familiar with the Python collection type hierarchy, but I believe Sequences are more generic, and read-only (as opposed to MutableSequence), and so it allows your function to accept not just lists, but strs as well. So if you need your function to be more general, it would make sense to use Sequence.
